# How to stop Iframe autoplay

Tags: php, html, iframe, streaming

This is my code :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="650" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.1malaysiatv.com.my/embed/player.php?ch=alhijrah&amp;width=920&amp;height=580" width="780" __idm_id__="0"></iframe>
```

How to make this code not play with itself . i mean autoplay=0 or autostart=false

i have done many style but cannot stop it from play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iframe cannot play anything by itself, so you also can't tell it not to autoplay. An iframe just loads a page (the src you provide), and it is the contents inside that page that can play, like in this case the video.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="650" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.1malaysiatv.com.my/embed/player.php?ch=alhijrah&amp;width=920&amp;height=580&amp;autoplay=false" width="780" __idm_id__="0"></iframe>
```